# How to show saved values of custom fields when product edit

Tags: magento2, module, addfield

I have added some custom fields to my product edit page and it is working now.
But I want to show the saved values in the edit.
Now i am able to show the values in text fields. but i don't know how to do the same in toggle box.

my xml for toggle box

```
       <field name="price_on_request">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4000</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price on request</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string">Price will not be displayed.</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

now i am using this method to set values when edit

```
 public function afterModifyData(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedInventory $subject,
    $data
) {
    $productId = $data['1']['product']['stock_data']['product_id'];
    $data[strval($productId)]['magenest']['price_on_request'] = 1;
    $data[strval($productId)]['magenest']['surcharge'] = 40;

    return $data;
}
```

now i can able to see the surcharge value is displaying fine, but toggle box is not showing as true/checked.

how can i manipulate the toggle box like here? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all
I got my solution now.

Just changed int to string is solved for me.

```
  `$data[strval($productId)]['magenest']['price_on_request'] = '1';`
```